# php/MySQL compare columns

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I am new to MySQL queries and a beginner at PHP, so I would love some help with this question.

Here is my scenario:
I have a system that allows users to save favourite items to the database. These items have about 20 different features (db columns) and only some features are included for each item.

What I want to do is write a query that looks at the users favourite items and compares them to other entries (rows) in the database and if they have the same number of features or more, I want the system to create a PDF and email it to them. Each feature column has the text "in" if it's included.

I don't need help with the PDF or email portion, just the MySQL/PHP portion.

I would very much appreciate any help, insight, or SQL queries that would be of help. Thank you for your time.

#### Update:

Thanks for your quick reply. I, however, am still confused and I actually left out a detail. In some of the fields, there is the text n/a, so the values not null, but I don't want it to be included. What is an "FK to the item". Are there any ways to counting the columns that include the text "in", instead of the reverse - counting all null values? Any examples of code would be amazing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The SQL queries depend on the table structure that you use. Show the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a FK to the item in your features table. You should set the default value of each of your feature column to NULL, then use the query from [How to count all NULL values in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295318/how-to-count-all-null-values-in-a-table) which has a query that will give you a row and the count of all NULL columns. Simply run through that and you'll know how many features are active for each item.