# How to find total count of all null values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any way to find the total count of all the **NULL** values in MySql table. I am able to find for a single column but for all the column I am not able to find the total count. Please let me know if anyone know the answer. TIA

I want to find sum of total null value count for each column.

```
FYI
I don't know all the `column` names in the table.
```

Comment: What is _"count of all the NULL"_ ? Count of all null values where?

Comment: Yes @AlmaDo. NULL values total count.

Comment: `select count(*) from a where name is null;` ??

Comment: What "Yes"? Where do you want to count your null values?

Comment: @PuneetPurohit: You need to be more specific. Do you mean null count on each column?

Comment: Suppose I have 5 columns in my table and four column value can be NULL so I want to find count of all the null value for the four columns.

Comment: Look at This link.
This will helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295318/how-to-count-all-null-values-in-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the total number of null values in a table.

```
SELECT SUM(col1 IS NULL) + SUM(col2 IS NULL) + SUM(col3 IS NULL) ... AS NullCount
FROM YourTable
```

If you need to do this for arbitrary tables, you'll have to write dynamic SQL, getting the table and column names from the `information_schema` database.

Comment: May be a tricky part is that count of columns isn't known (or may be even their names are not known)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select sum(case when id is null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when name is null then 1 else 0 end) as count
from a;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/a9402/2/0)