# SQL count empty cells in unknown number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table with an unknown number of columns (and unknown column names too) with different types of data (can be anything from bit to nvarchar or datetime) like the following:

```
ID   | Col2 | Col3 | Customer |  ..(etc)..
1    | NULL |  0   |  CustA   |    
2    | valA |  1   |  NULL    |
3    | valB | NULL |  (empty) |
```

I need a query which counts all NULL and empty cells on every column and outputs the result like this:

```
Column_Name  |  No_Of_Empty_And_Null_Cells | 
   Col2      |             1               |
   Col3      |             1               |
 Customer    |             2               |
 (etc...)    |                             |
```

I understand that I have to use dynamic queries and UNPIVOT, but my SQL knowledge is nowhere near that!

[How to count all NULL values in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295318/how-to-count-all-null-values-in-a-table) does not seem to work as it is MySQL related, not MS SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count all NULL values in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295318/how-to-count-all-null-values-in-a-table)

Comment: @webmaster, your *possible duplicate* is for `MySQL` while this runs against `SQL Server`

Comment: Yes understood late, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this dynamic SQL code out:

```
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(100)='dbo';
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)='SomeTable';

DECLARE @DynamicSelect VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
  STUFF((SELECT 'UNION SELECT ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS COLUMN_NAME' + 
         ', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @schema + '.' + @tableName + ' WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL) AS No_Of_Null_Cells '
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
         WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@schema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@tableName AND c.IS_NULLABLE='YES'
         FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,6,'')
);
exec (@DynamicSelect)


DECLARE @DynamicSelect2 VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
  STUFF((SELECT 'UNION SELECT ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS COLUMN_NAME' + 
         ', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @schema + '.' + @tableName + ' WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + '])) ='''') AS No_Of_Empty_Cells '
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
         WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@schema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@tableName AND c.DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%'
         FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,6,'')
);
exec (@DynamicSelect2)
```

Comment: I had to edit the second dynamic query to include Nulls (as I needed results in a single tabular format) but it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to return the fields with null or empty values from a table.
Via generating and executing a dynamic query with an unpivot.
Tested on a SQL Server 2014.

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'YourDatabase';
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH COL AS (
    SELECT c.name
    FROM sys.objects o
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
      AND s.name = @SchemaName 
      AND o.name = @TableName
      AND c.is_nullable = 1
)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT up.column_name, up.total_empty 
FROM (
 SELECT ' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = SUM(IIF(LEN(RTRIM(' + QUOTENAME(name) + '))>0,0,1))'
    FROM COL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') + '
 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ') q
 UNPIVOT
 (total_empty for column_name in ('+
  STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name) FROM COL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ')
   +')
) up where up.total_empty > 0 order by up.column_name';

--SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Just tested it myself, works nicely with NULLs but I need to include the empty cells as well!

Comment: @espressionist Indeed, I overlooked that.  Fixed now.  Now it'll also count those with an empty text or when it only contains spaces. I added a RTRIM just in case, but while testing I discovered that the LEN of a varchar with only spaces also equals 0.  An interesting little T-SQL quirck.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This answer is for MySQL** (did not read carefully at first)

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296253/1201725), I think this result will count your all "null" cells:

```
SET @db = 'your_database_name'; -- database
SET @tb = 'your_table_name'; -- table
SET @x = ''; -- will hold the column names with ASCII method applied to retrieve the number of the first char
SET @numcolumns = 0; -- will hold the number of columns in the table

-- figure out how many columns we have
SELECT count(*) into @numcolumns FROM information_schema.columns where table_name=@tb and table_schema=@db;

-- we have to prepare some query from all columns of the table
SELECT group_concat(CONCAT('ASCII(',column_name,')')) into @x from information_schema.columns where table_name=@tb and table_schema=@db;
-- after this query we have a variable separated with comma like
-- ASCII(col1),ASCII(col2),ASCII(col3)

-- we now generate a query to concat the columns using comma as separator (null values are omitted from concat)
-- then figgure out how many times the comma is in that substring (this is done by using length(value)-length(replace(value,',',''))
-- the number returned is how many non null columns we have in that column
-- then we deduct the number from the known number of columns, calculated previously
-- the +1 is added because there is no comma for single value
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT @numcolumns - (length(CONCAT_WS(\',\',', @x, '))-length(replace(CONCAT_WS(\',\',', @x, '),\',\',\'\')) + 1) FROM ',@db,'.',@tb,';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
-- after this execution we have returned for each row the number of null columns
-- I will leave to you to add a sum() group call if you want to find the null values for the whole table
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but your answer is referring to MySQL and does not seem to work in MSSQL

Comment: Ah so sorry, I just wrongly estimated. Thanks for the warning.